# How Update the data shown in one page after changing the data in database from the second page

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

In my Home page I am fetching data from Firestore database and showing them using a ListView.builder. More specifically, I am showing all the subjects that belongs to the current user. In home page there is a button which takes us the FirstPage where users can create new subject. When user create a subject, that subject is added to the database. But when user go back to the Home page, data shown there should be updated, i,e. the list of subjects shown there should contain the newly created subject.
I am using streamController to call setState in Home page after the new subject is added to database but it is not working i,e. when user go back to home page it shows the previous data only. All other things are working (i,e. data is successfully added to data base. When I again reload the home page it shows updated data)

Can someone look into it and tell me what's wrong with my approach ? Or if it is possible with the provider package, then can you please give me an example of that in similar situation.

Here is my code,

```
// Stream controller
StreamController<bool> streamControllerHome = StreamController<bool>();

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple
          ),
          home: Home(stream: streamControllerHome.stream),
        );
  }
}


// Code for Home page
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream<bool> stream;
  const Home({Key? key, required this.stream}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  setStateHome(bool check) {
    if (check) {
      setState(() {
        
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    if (!streamControllerHome.hasListener) {
      widget.stream.listen((event) {
        setStateHome(event);
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(child: Text('Error'));
              }
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(child: Text('No Data'),);
              }
              Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
              List<String> subjects = data['subjects'];
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: subjects.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(Icons.book),
                            const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                            Text(subjects[index]),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },              
              );

          }
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return const FirstPage();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


// Code for FirstPage

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FirstPage'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: textController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Subject Name',
              hintText: 'Type the subject here',
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .update({'subjects' : FieldValue.arrayUnion([textController.text])});
              streamControllerHome.add(true);
            }, 
            child: const Text('Create Subject')
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is broken:

```
future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get(),
```

for reasons given in the first few paragraphs of `FutureBuilder` documentation, and illustrated in my oft-referenced video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

In brief, you cannot build a future as the `future:` parameter of a `FutureBuilder`.  You need to lift it out into State.

Comment: if it get contructed only once, how to update the screen after adding new data to the database? I want to show the updated list of 'subjects' in the home screen each time the user adds a new subject

Comment: Use .snapshots and StreamBuilder

Comment: can you please give an example